# How to find the SVN branch(s) or commits that resulted in the modification of certain parts of the code

Tags: eclipse, svn

Sometimes, I need to know when certain changes were committed to the SVN branch or trunk. For example, I see a code block and I want to find the approximate date when it was added, and what is the commit info used. Usually, the context of certain changes are described on the commit level, and the developer doesn't add comments to describe why it was added.

I am using Eclipse 2019-09 and SVN plugin.

Tarek

Answer (score 0):

###### Display of Changes (Using Tortoise SVN and KDiff3)

To view the changes, follow the steps below:

- Right click on Tortoise SVN icon and select "Show Monitor".

  `Screenshot 1`: [Display of Tortoise SVN Project Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMTl8.png)
- To connect to the remote repository, SlikSVN registration information is entered.

  `Screenshot 2`: [Connect to remote repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW2rc.png)
- Use the GUI for commit notifications, file history and more.

  `Screenshot 3`: [Display of changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxvxx.png)
- For example, to view the contents of the files in the sixth revision, double click on the file name and the KDiff3 windows opens.

  `Screenshots 4`: [By double clicking the file, the KDiff3 windows opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2WJw.png)
- Changes made using the KDiff3 windows are displayed at the file content level.

  `Screenshots 5`: [Display of file content level changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9qGF.png)
- In addition, differences between revisions (unformatted) and commit declarations can be viewed in history via the Eclipse IDE.

  `Screenshot 6`: [Viewing revisions via Eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPQW1.png)